# python is there a way to compare two datetime keys by minute and get the max value of those keys?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

Hello guys currently lets say I have a dictionary of shows

```
 shows = {
        "mad.men": [
            "2021-02-03 15:15:20.419000-05:00",
            "1612384580",
            0.1116604417347844
        ],
        "breaking.bad": [
            "2021-02-03 15:18:43.186000-05:00",
            "1612369123",
            3.60979356628377e-06
        ],
        "the.shield": [
            "2021-02-03 15:16:51.357000-05:00",
            "1612373511",
            0.030060711756050296
        ],
        "game.of.thrones": [
            "2021-02-03 15:14:48.075000-05:00",
            "1612384248",
            3.9553624669451892,
            [
                "2021-02-03 15:15:29.043000-05:00",
                "1612384349",
                3.9553624669451892
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Here I have default values of the shows by timestamp

```
 defaults = {
        "mad.men": [
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:14:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:15:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:16:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:17:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:18:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:19:00-05:00": 0 
        ],
        "breaking.bad": [
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:14:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:15:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:16:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:17:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:18:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:19:00-05:00": 0
        ],
        "the.shield": [
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:14:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:15:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:16:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:17:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:18:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:19:00-05:00": 0
            },
            
        ],
        "game.of.thrones": [
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:14:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:15:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:16:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:17:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:18:00-05:00": 0
            },
            {
                "2021-02-03 15:19:00-05:00": 0
            },
        ]
    }
```

what I want to achieve is to iterate through  the shows key, value pairs to the defaults key, value pairs . If the timestamp matches by minute for  the shows dictionary and defaults dictionary then substitute  defaults dictionary  value for  the shows value.  For example shows `game.of.thrones` is 15:15:20.419000 is within the same minute as the defaults 15:15:00 then substitute the default value which is 0 to the shows value which is 3.95.

```
so the end result I would like is : 

defaults = {
    "mad.men": [
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:14:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:15:20.419000-05:00": 0.1116604417347844
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:16:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:17:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:18:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:19:00-05:00": 0 
    ],
    "breaking.bad": [
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:14:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:15:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:16:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:17:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:18:43.186000-05:00": 3.60979356628377e-06
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:19:00-05:00": 0
    ],
    "the.shield": [
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:14:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:15:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:16:51.357000-05:00": 0.030060711756050296
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:17:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:18:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:19:00-05:00": 0
        },

    ],
    "game.of.thrones": [
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:14:48.075000-05:00":  3.9553624669451892
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:15:29.043000-05:00": 3.9553624669451892
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:16:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:17:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:18:00-05:00": 0
        },
        {
            "2021-02-03 15:19:00-05:00": 0
        },
    ]
}
```

How would I implement this logic  here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.replace()` function to replace seconds and microseconds of the time under `shows`.

Example: Let's assume that you have stored the `datetime` object of the show as `showtime` and the default time as `defaulttime` . Then:

`showtime.replace(second=0, microsecond=0) == defaulttime`

---

It would be more convenient if you could alter the dictionary `defaults[show_name]` from list to dict. ie,

```
defaults = {
  "mad.men": {
     "2021-02-03 15:14:00-05:00": 0,
     "2021-02-03 15:15:00-05:00": 0,
     "2021-02-03 15:16:00-05:00": 0
  }
}
```

This way the comparison can be done in `O(n)` time instead of `O(n^2)` time.

```
for key, value in shows.items():
  altered_show_time = value[0].replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
  if altered_show_time in defaults[key]:
    defaults[key][altered_show_time] = value[2]
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but I also would like to know how would you go about assigning  the value of the `show` dictionary to the default dictionary value?

Comment: I have illustrated an efficient way to achieve what you are expecting.